# Layover at San Francisco International Airport

Tags: layovers, luggage-storage, sfo

We have a 6 hour layover at SFO. Is that enough time to see the town? Is there a bus or should we take a taxi? What about our 2 carry-on 17 lb. bags?

Comment: This question largely answers the 'is it enough time' aspect of your question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14842/5-5-hr-layover-in-san-francisco-international-airport-enough-time-to-visit-city

Comment: As to storing luggage, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30572/how-much-to-store-luggage-at-sfo-for-24-hours